Does C# optimise operations that are repeated (Common Subexpression Elimination)
Given this minimal reproducible example:
using System;

int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(k+l);
Console.WriteLine(k+l);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.WriteLine(k+l);

Is it worth it to manually do:
using System;

int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int sum = k + l;
Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.WriteLine(sum);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Console.WriteLine(sum);


Dotnet does various optimizations when it takes your code and steps it down to intermediate language. I believe one of its rules is to inline and fully qualify variables when it possibly can do so, so in IL your second code snippet will become your first. You can verify this with IlSpy, which has an extension for VS22 also

@Narish wonder why didn't you answer the question with that comment information.

@Narish That is factually incorrect https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTd2AHbAEA1gQC8BPsAB0ABQCGAJwDOAUxYkA9r0XqIyyQCVlsmABk+qtmwDcXbtQkEIo8fxkKVazdt0Gjp8+zWtnbI6ACcLILwEEHYdjShEVExNnHxROEsAEQAEsoQEOpZsekZSdElNAC+wcH4RIxMqOycafEOwmISbkqqGlo6eobGZrwWle38js7dcr2eAz7D/mOBqaUOigCuALbOwvCO6+mJLNs7EyGZ55fcp7n5hcXH8ac3LwQ12FVAA===. The JITter may do so in machine code, but not the C# compiler in IL.

C# compiler doesn't really do any optimizations at all. Your code gets translated pretty directly into IL (except for more complex constructs such as await or yield which are reduced first). Only the JITter does optimizations, and probably would optimize simple addition of local variables. Not everything can be optimized like you think, due to side-effects, threading implications, and sheer complexity of the optimizations.

Is there a way to see the optimisations the JIT compiler do? Apart from benchmarking both pieces of code I guess by running them 10^7 times each.

Cleptus because I was unclear on the info. I have heard it discussed but I couldn't find an exact source on it. I wanted to offer ILSpy as that was something that could help. @Charlieface thank you for the clarification, I am looking at the Il and JIT in sharplab and  its clear the optimization happens somewhere in between IL -> ASM and not code -> IL. I can't read assembly but from the pointer addresses there *is optimization happening during this stage

@FluidMechanicsPotentialFlows by focusing on best practices, and big O notation you will never have to really stress over what the dotnet compilation tools are doing. Sharplab.io is a one stop place to see both IL and the JIT assembly but its online sadly, I'm not sure of any Visual Studio tools/extensions that can help with this

Sharplab or LINQpad is good for this. https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAhgZwLYwCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUPgMwAERNAwjQN4U3t235Q0CyAFAEoWbDmICWAOzg0A1jQC8NKXAB0ABUQAnZAFN+DAPaTkhgDa7VAJV2IMAGSn7BggNyix7FTTOLl0jW09A2NTC2tbBychNw9PfGIATn5ZbDNY8k8OBOTU9PdMrLok/gAiAAldMzNDUoyi4ty0+o4AXzi46joeXkIhEUKs73klFUCdfSMTc0sbO0dJZxah6R8/Mc0JkOnwuajFmIKG72QAV1Q/eWwfI6Kc/jPUZfiSx+exe4qqmrrbrPu3n8aO1yK0gA it basically depends which JITter is used, and whether Debug mode is on or not. You can see in that link that it doesn't optimize. The CPU may also have hidden optimzations.

The real question is why you care: what code are you running that so significantly depends on such a micro-optimization?

The question was purely theoretical I'm currently learning C# and wanted to know more about how things work under the hood.

Thank you for the link, I didn't know we could actually see the JIT-generated-machine-code disassembled back into assembly
